# When I add progress bar it throws Module not found: Error: Can't resolve in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, progress-bar

I'm new on React and I'm stuck on something. I added a new component as a 'react-customizable-progressbar' in my project. I have the following files in yellow. These were the ones that I created.
[image]
The problem point to

> ERROR in ./src/example1.js 6:0-73
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './CircularProgressBarContainer' in 'C:\Alex Maricoiu\Projects\React projects\project1\src'
> Failed to compile.
> CircularProgressBarContainer.tsx have the following code:

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from "react";
import ICustomIndicatorProperties from './IProgressBarProperties';
import ProgressBar from 'react-customizable-progressbar'

const CustomProgressIndicator : FunctionComponent<ICustomIndicatorProperties> = ({value, title}) => {
    return (
      <div className="text-and-value" style={{width: "29em"}}>
      <div className="title-text">{title}</div>
      <div className="custom-progress-bar">
      <ProgressBar
            radius={100}
            progress={value}
            strokeWidth={18}
            strokeColor="#5d9cec"
            strokeLinecap="square"
            trackStrokeWidth={18}
        >
           <div className="indicator">
                <div>{value}%</div>
            </div>
        </ProgressBar>
  </div>
  </div>
    )
};

export default CustomProgressIndicator;
```

Example1.js:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {CustomProgressIndicator} from './CircularProgressBarContainer';

function Button(props) {
    return (
      <button onClick={props.onClickFunc}>
        Increment by 1
      </button>
    );
  }
  
  function Display(props){
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const incrementValue = () => setCounter(counter+1);
    return (
    <div> 
        <Button onClickFunc={incrementValue}/>
        <b> Current value is:  {counter}</b>
        <CustomProgressIndicator 
            value={counter}
            title ='Indicator Exercise 1'
         />
    </div>
    )
  }
  
  
  function App(props){
    return (
    <div>
      <Display />
    </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default App;
```

The Interface file has (IProgressBarProperties.tsx):

```
interface ICustomIndicatorProperties {
    title: string;
    value: number;
}

export default ICustomIndicatorProperties;
```

And Main.js:

```
import './Main.css';
import Example1 from './example1';
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <>
            <div className='header'>Alex React Examples</div><div className='content'>
            <h3>Example #1</h3>
            <div id='example1Node'>
              <Example1 />
            </div>
          </div>
         </>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default App;
```

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import MainApp from './Main';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MainApp />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-customizable-progressbar": "^1.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I use Node.js 19.3.0.
I tried to find from the browser console what is the problem, but I was stuck.
I tried to remove the node_modules and run this command again in terminal: npm install.
If I remove the reference to the file where is the progress bar the app is working, but with that failed with the error mentioned. Is there any way to find a solution to that error?

Thank you in advance

I use Node.js 19.3.0.
I tried to find from the browser console what is the problem, but I was stuck.
I tried to remove the node_modules and run this command again in terminal: npm install.
If I remove the reference to the file where is the progress bar the app is working, but with that failed with the error mentioned. Is there any way to find a solution to that error?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `import {CustomProgressIndicator} from './CircularProgressBarContainer';` with `import CustomProgressIndicator from './CircularProgressBarContainer';`, since you are using *export default*. Curly braces are used for normal (non-default) *export*. Alternatively remove *default* from *export default*.

Comment: Still have the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE/RESOLVE**

I came back with a solution. After I investigate a little seems that there was a incorrect path to the local module created (to the local TSX file).
The UPDATE was in Example1.js. When I put the path, intellisense show me the correct way to import and I hit Enter in order to complete the path. Fine for this. The import looked like this

```
import {CustomProgressIndicator} from './CircularProgressBarContainer';
```

The problem was just right here. I correct like it is bellow and it worked.

```
import {CustomProgressIndicator} from './CircularProgressBarContainer.tsx';
```

The final result is this. The component marked in yellow was the problem.
[image]

Thank you everyone.